# VS Express 2013 Error DEP1700: The recipe file "xxxxx.appxrecipe" does not exist. You may need to build your project

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I just repaired/reinstalled my Windows 8.1 PC, and then I install VS 2013 Express.
But every-time I build my projects (all of my projects), it threw me this error :

> Error 1   Error : DEP1700 : The recipe file "xxxxx.appxrecipe" does not
>   exist. You may need to build your project.

I've tried these step:

- Repairing my VS 2013 Express
- Uninstalling VS 2013 Express-Restarting PC-Installing VS 2013 Express
- Freshly check-out my projects and build it from beginning.

But none of those are works for me.
Anyone can help me?
Because before reinstalling my PC everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 
I decided to install VS 2013 Update 4, and it somehow fixed my problem...not sure what was happen.

Comment: I'm getting this problem in the latest version of Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Same, getting on VS 2017.

Answer (score 10):

I had this same issue with a Xamarin Forms application when I attempted to run the UWP instance on my local machine. After a bit of digging it turns out that in Configuration Manager (Right click solution file -> Configuration Manager) BUILD was unticked while DEPLOY was ticked. Never going to work as the project can't deploy if it hasn't built!

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer, not only for Xamarin, but also for UWP projects. Somehow the build was deactivated for my main app in one of my configurations - deploy AND build must be checked for the main app, otherwise the appxrecipe is not generated.

Answer (score 3):

On Visual studio 2017, simply restarting Visual studio solves the problem (No need to clean or delete obj/bin folders).

Answer (score 0):

For a packaged WinUI project, you should also check if Package.appxmanifest exists

Answer (score 0):

For WinUI projects, the error stopped when I switched from "Packaged" to "Unpackaged" config when debugging.